# Checkbox with PHP form

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

I'm working on a form on my website that would display different categories, checked or not regarding if the category contain the product or not. One product can have multiple categories.

```php
<form method='post' action='action.php'> 
            <?php foreach ($ls_categories as $c): ?> 
                <input 
                    type='checkbox' 
                    name='checkboxvar[]' 
                    value='<?= $c->id ?>'  
                    <?= (contains($c, $categories)) ? 'checked' : "" ?>> 

                    <?= $c->title ?><br>
                <?php endforeach; ?> 
            <input type='submit'> 
        </form>
```

When I look at the source code I got this :

```
<input
       type='checkbox' 
       name='checkboxvar[]' 
       value='1' 
       checked> 

       Title1<br>
<input 
       type='checkbox' 
       name='checkboxvar[]' 
       value='2' 
       > 

       Title2<br>
```

But on the screen I see this :

```
 checked> Cat1
 > Cat2
 > Cat3
 checked> Cat4
 > Cat5
```

(with the boxes on the left, all empty)

Probably something wrong in my foreach loop but I don't see it.

Displaying categories is the first part. After that I want to edit the product's categories with what will be checked when submitting the form. Any idea how to do that?

English is not my first langage so maybe you'll need some more precisions. Feel free to ask if you don't understand well. Thanks!

EDIT :

Tried with `"checked='checked'` too.

If you look on that screenshot, you'll see the `>` after checked does not close the `input` tag (the color is different), so there might be a syntax problem somewhere here. What do you think?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojt6R.jpg)

Comment: Try checked="checked" rather than just checked

Comment: Check on the edit, tried that too. Look at the screenshot, I think that's why it's not working. What do you think?

Comment: try ending input as />

Comment: can you paste complete output

Comment: The source code seems ok to me but nothing on the web page, just empty checkboxes with the name, that's all. Here's the code source output for one <input> tag : <input 
                                    type='checkbox' 
                                    name='checkboxvar[]' 
                                    value='1'                                  
                                    checked /> 
                                    
                                    Truc<br>

Answer (score 0):

You can't use html comments inside tag. So remove it for proper output.

Comment: Yeah, about that. I don't really understand why but when I delete it, it doesn't even show "checked >" in plain text. Nothing but in the source code I still have the `checked = 'checked'` or `checked` depending which one I use. Have you seen the screenshot? Maybe that's my problem or it doesn't really matter?

Comment: Really? Checkbox are checked?

Comment: damn, just used the same code as you but : http://pastebin.com/cJuTH4wq, http://imgur.com/rApqAIW

Comment: Seems that function `contains($c, $categories)` returns false for all categories. That is why checkboxes are not checked.

Comment: This is weird cause I had the "> checked" displaying on the page for the correct categories. I var_dumped my $categories and it returns an array with the matching categories. Here's my contains function : http://pastebin.com/RBHVPece

Comment: error in `contain`. change if to `if ($elem->id == $row->id) return $row;`

Comment: Still not working. In the source code the the "checked" appear but nothing on the page. http://pastebin.com/MyHdbpmy

Comment: It is strange. Try to check it in other browsers.

Comment: Not working in Chrome and Safari. Working in Firefox. What. The. F*ck.

Comment: may be cache... ctrl+f5